Prove that $d_3d_3^*+d_3^*d_3=-\nabla^2$
Consider the geometry in $\mathbb R^3$, define
$$d_3=dx\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+dy\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+dz\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$
We then define the Hodge star operator $*_3:\Omega^p(\mathbb R^3)\rightarrow \Omega^{3-p}(\mathbb R^3)$ on differential forms that
$$1\stackrel{*_3}{\mapsto}dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\\
dx\stackrel{*_3}{\mapsto}dy\wedge dz\\
dy\stackrel{*_3}{\mapsto}dz\wedge dx\\
dz\stackrel{*_3}{\mapsto}dx\wedge dy\\
dx\wedge dy\stackrel{*_3}{\mapsto}dz\\
dy\wedge dz\stackrel{*_3}{\mapsto}dx\\
dz\wedge dx\stackrel{*_3}{\mapsto}dy\\
dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\stackrel{*_3}{\mapsto}1
$$
It is clear that we have $(*_3)^2=1$ on all $\Omega^\forall(\mathbb R^3)$. We then define the adjoint operator $d_3^*$ of $d_3$ in $\mathbb R^3$ by
$$d_3^*=(-1)^p*_3d_3*_3:\Omega^p(\mathbb R^3)\longrightarrow\Omega^{p-1}(\mathbb R^3).$$
Prove that we have $\boxed{d_3d_3^*+d_3^*d_3=-\nabla^2}$.
(Here $\nabla$ is just  the Laplacian operator when $p=0$, when $p\neq0$ we extend the definition to $\Omega^p(\mathbb R^3)$ component-wise with respect to the basis as above, for example $\nabla^2(fdx+gdy\wedge dz)=(\nabla^2 f)dx+(\nabla^2 g)dy\wedge dz$.)
We cannot simply let $f$ be an function on $\mathbb R^3$ and prove $(d_3d_3^*+d_3^*d_3)(f)=-\nabla^2(f)$, since we obviously have $d_3^* f=0$ but $d_3d_3^*+d_3^*d_3\neq d_3^*d_3$, so this can only be an example for illustration, there must be some other ways of proving this. My question is, how? Thank you!

This is usually the definition of the Laplacian. How are you defining $\nabla^2$ on $p$-forms when $p\ne 0$?

When $p\neq0$ I extend the definition to $\Omega^p(\mathbb R^3)$ component-wise with respect to the basis as above, for example $\nabla^2(fdx+gdy\wedge dz)=(\nabla^2 f)dx+(\nabla^2 g)dy\wedge dz$ (maybe I should write this in above) @TedShifrin

Why can't you just show $dd^*f  = -\nabla^2f$? It's a direct calculation.

Because I wanted to prove $d_3d_3^*+d_3^*d_3=-\nabla^2$ for all $\Omega^p(\mathbb R^3)$, not just $p=0$. @ArcticChar

But then it's obvious, since $d(dx)=d(dy)=\dots=0$ and since $d^(dx)=d^(dy)=\dots=0$ and likewise for the basis $2$- and $3$-forms. With a non-flat metric, of course, your definition doesn't work.

You are correct in your assesment that $d^*_3f=0$ for some given $0$-form on your manifold $M$. This will then trivially yield;
$$(d_3d^*_3+d^*_3d_3)f=-(*d_3*d_3)f=-\nabla^2f$$
So this definition works for $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ but its real utility is that it works for general forms on $M$ rather than just for smooth functions. Consider the $1$-form $\omega =f\space dx$;
$$(d_3d^*_3+d^*_3d_3)\omega=(d_3d^*_3+d^*_3d_3)fdx=(d_3d_3^*)fdx+(d^*_3d_3)fdx$$
Our first term will yield;
$$-(d_3*d_3*)fdx=-(d_3*d_3)fdy\wedge dz=-(d_3*)[\partial_xf]dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$$
$$=-d_3(\partial_xf)=-\partial^2_xfdx-\partial_{yx}fdy-\partial_{zx}fdz$$
While our second term gives us;
$$(d^*_3d_3)fdx=(*d_3*)[\partial_{y}fdy\wedge dx+\partial_{z}fdz\wedge dx]$$
$$=*d_3[-\partial_{y}fdz+\partial_{z}fdy]$$
$$=*[-\partial_{xy}fdx\wedge dz-\partial^2_{y}fdy\wedge dz+\partial_{xz}fdx\wedge dy+\partial^2_{z}fdz\wedge dy]$$
$$=[\partial_{xy}f\space dy-\partial^2_{y}fdx+\partial_{xz}f\space dz-\partial^2_{z}f\space dx]$$
Adding our terms then yields;
$$(d_3d^*_3+d^*_3d_3)\omega=-[\partial^2_{x}f+\partial^2_{x}f+\partial^2_{z}f]dx$$
Abusing the notation a bit allows us to then write;
$$(d_3d^*_3+d^*_3d_3)\omega=-[\nabla^2]\omega$$
This, of course, holds for general $n$-forms on $M$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry#Hodge_Laplacian
